# Wait for API call return before proceeding

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I am very weak in javascript but I think I understand what's going wrong.  Just not fluent enough to know how to fix it or even how to correctly write it.  I have a VueJS app that sends requests to an API with an `access_token`.  When that `access_token` expiries it sends a `refresh_token` to the API and gets a new `access_token`.  I want it to then redo the request it was running when it expired.  Using the code below I get strange behavior.  When it hits the `401` I can see it access the `/token` endpoint and get a new `access_token` however the next call to `/brewery` is using the old `access_token`.  This happens about 5 times before a call to `/brewery` finally uses the new `access_token` and the loop stops.  My guess is that when I call `this.loaded()` the call to `auth.refreshToken()` hasn't finished yet?

```
loaded(access_token){
        var headers;
        if(access_token)
        {
            headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token }
        }
        else
        {
            headers = auth.getAuthHeader();
        }
        axios.get(this.getBaseUrl + '/brewery/', { headers })
             .then((response) => {
                this.breweries = response.data.data.slice(0);                    
             })
             .catch((error) => {                    
                if(error.response.status == 401)
                {
                    console.log("error 401");
                    var new_access_token = auth.refreshToken();
                    this.loaded(new_access_token);
                }
            });
    }
```

Auth class

```
refreshToken(context) {
var token = 
{
  refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
  grant_type: 'refresh_token'
};
token = querystring.stringify(token);
axios.post(LOGIN_URL, token)
  .then((response) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access_token);
    this.checkLoggedIn();
    if(!this.isAdmin())
    {
      context.error = "You are not an admin user";
    }
    return response.data.access_token;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    if(error.response){
      if(error.response.status == 400)
      {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        context.error = error.response.data;
      }
    }
  })
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like promise chaining/structure issue. To make the call to `this.loaded` occur after the call to `auth.refreshToken` has completed you should make the `refreshToken` method return a promise. Specifically, it should return the `axios.post` call. That `axios.post` call, when successful is actually executing this line `return response.data.access_token;` and resolving the token. Now when you make a call to `auth.refreshToken` you should append a `then` block like so:

```
auth.refreshToken().then((token) => { this.loaded(token) })
```

Without structuring this code in a synchronous manner, you're going to get multiple calls to `this.loaded` because each one will fail with a stale token... or at the least an undefined token.